# Is it possible to make Hibernate 3.1 generate a left outer join for a child entity?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, java-ee-6

**Edited to reflect earlier omission:**
I want to define a relationship of 0 to 1 rows where there will never be more than 1 child row:

```
...
@JoinColumn(name="INVENTORY_ID", referencedColumnName="INVENTORY_ID")
@OneToOne
private QOH qoh;
...
```

So my problem is I have tried every way to use @OneToOne without @JoinColumn and with it and no matter what I do the SQL generated by Hibernate when selecting a subset of fields causes an inner join meaning that the Item records that have no QOH record are not returned:

```
...
SELECT i.inventoryId,i.name,i.qoh.quantity FROM Item i;
...
```

If I had full control over the database I'd enforce the creation of a QOH record anytime an Item is created but I don't control the database nor the access to it.  Can Hibernate do this for a child entity?:

```
...
SELECT ... FROM Item i LEFT OUTER JOIN QOH q ON q.INVENTORY_ID = i.INVENTORY_ID
...
```

instead of:

```
...
SELECT ... FROM Item i, QOH q WHERE q.INVENTORY_ID = i.INVENTORY_ID
...
```

Comment: Apart from the type of query being generated, are you able to achieve your expected results ? If not can you paste the code ?

Comment: @Jay - no I could only achieve the results I wanted by removing the child relationship from the Entity and executing two queries.  With the child relationship Items that did not have a QOH record were not returned.  I want a null QOH child when it does not exist and an instantiated QOH when it does.  Everything I tried resulted in no record when the QOH was missing, that is to say, an inner join instead of an outer join.

Comment: Have you tried `@OneToOne(optional = true)`?

Comment: It would be easier if you post your code.

Comment: @Jay - I did, I simply omitted everything that wasn't relevant to the question.  qoh is a field on entity Item, but that is irrelevant.  QOH is an entity.  When I do SELECT i FROM Item i, it does not return any Items that don't have a corresponding QOH

Comment: @Jay - I was wrong, your were right, I had failed to include the relevant code.  I will answer my own question and fix my question now that I found a solution to my problem online I realized I left out a very important detail of my source code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your **Item** entity,

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    private QOH qoh;
```

This actually creates a 1 to 0..1 relation between Item & QOH.

This would generate left outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Piecing together answers to other stackoverflow.com questions that are very similar to mine I found the solution:

@Jay 's answer is a step in the right direction (would be right answer if the original version of my question was what I was really asking, overnight, and with @Jay 's comments I realized my question was incomplete.  Using @Jay 's answer and the following changes to my HQL:

```
...
SELECT i.inventoryId,i.name,q.quantity FROM Item i LEFT OUTER JOIN i.qoh as q
...
```

instead of

```
...
SELECT i.inventoryId,i.name,i.qoh.quantity FROM Item i
...
```

Basically, adding the LEFT OUTER JOIN reference to the field in Item you are telling Hibernate to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN when populating that field, thus allowing nulls.  Making the field optional does not automatically make it LEFT OUTER JOIN in every query, it just prevents it from throwing an error when you use LEFT OUTER JOIN in your HQL.

And please correct me if I'm wrong.